# Can I make Julia forget a method from the REPL

Tags: methods, julia

If I'm playing in the REPL and I've defined a few different methods for a function:

```
julia> methods(next)
# 3 methods for generic function "next":
next(i::BigInt) at none:1
next(i::Int64) at none:1
next(i) at none:1
```

Can I make Julia forget some or all of these?

Comment: `workspace()` will replace the top-level module with a clean workspace, but it is not selective, i.e. it'll clear everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.

> Julia does not have an analog of MATLAB’s `clear` function; once a name
>   is defined in a Julia session (technically, in module `Main`), it is
>   always present.
>
> If memory usage is your concern, you can always replace objects with
>   ones that consume less memory. For example, if `A` is a gigabyte-sized
>   array that you no longer need, you can free the memory with `A = 0`. The
>   memory will be released the next time the garbage collector runs; you
>   can force this to happen with `gc()`.

([source](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#how-do-i-delete-an-object-in-memory))

Comment: Thanks! Memory's not my concern, here. I've just made errors in method definitions while playing with different types. I want to get rid of the method definitions that have errors so that there is a single generic method that I can fix, rather than needing to fix all of them. I could just restart the REPL, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to manipulate the MethodTable like this.

Comment: There is `workspace()`, but it will clear everything: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/base/?highlight=workspace#Base.workspace