# Is there a way to undo `using` in Julia?

Tags: module, julia

Suppose in the Julia console I do

```
using Gadfly
```

And then realise I actually want to use a different plot command

```
using Winston
```

It seems that `plot()` will still use the Gadfly version. Is there any way to *stop* using Gadfly?

```
using !Gadfly
!using Gadfly
unuse Gadfly
```

Something like that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33927523/2541573

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the link by @Jubobs, there is currently not a way to selectively stop using a package, or selectively remove a definition from the REPL (similar to Matlab's `clear` command if you are familiar with it). So the short answer is no.

However, you can reference functions from specific modules by using `Gadfly.plot()`, or `Winston.plot()`. This doesn't provide you a solution to your problem if you have already written the code, but it is still an option for future work.

There is the `workspace()` command but that will **remove everything from the `Main` module** and will import a fresh Julia environment. <s>You **will lose** all the functions and variables you have defined... so use it wisely</s>

As @Matt B pointed out, you don't actually **lose** your functions and variables. They are moved to a module called `LastMain`. So if I have a function defined called `myfunc()`, and I call `workspace()`, then attempting to call `myfunc()` at the REPL will result in an `UndefVarError`. However, you will still be able access this function by calling `LastMain.myfunc()`. This is true of anything that was defined in the REPL before your call to `workspace()`.

Comment: You don't really lose them, they just get stashed into the `LastMain` module.

Comment: `workspace()` was deprecated in Julia 0.7 and removed in 1.0 (see [Julia 0.7 release notes, deprecations section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.7/NEWS/#Deprecated-or-removed-1) and [Pull request #25046](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25046) merged in late 2017). There is a still opened issue [#32129](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/32129) about adding a `restart()` command.

Comment: See also Julia's forum thread [How to clear variables and/or whole work space](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-clear-variables-and-or-whole-work-space/10149/17) with messages from 2018 to early 2022.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, you cannot unload a package in Julia. The only way to do that would be to restart the Julia repl. However, if you want to use a specific function from a package, you can us `Winston.plot()` or `Gadfly.plot()`. Thus will ensure, you're using the right function from the desired namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when comparing different plotting frameworks.
The final solution is to use `import` instead of `using`.
You have to write a little more code than before:

```
Gadfly.plot(...)
Winston.plot(...)
```

vs

```
plot(...)
```

However, there's no need to restart REPL.
For JIT language like Julia, restarting wastes too much compilation time.